# How to get overall error status on Material UI DataGrid?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, mui-x

I am using Material UI DataGrid component to render EXCEL file. Each Excel file has several column Names and have specific types. For example:

```
const columns = [
    {
        "field": "uwgroup",
        "headerName": "Group",
        "minWidth": 200,
        "editable": true
    },
    {
        "field": "Amazing column Name ",
        "flex": 1,
        "minWidth": 150,
        "editable": true
    },
    {
        "field": "Building TSI",
        "type": 'number',
        "flex": 1,
        "minWidth": 150,
        "editable": true
    },
    {
        "field": "dev",
        "flex": 1,
        "minWidth": 150,
        "editable": true
    }
]
```

The column Name `Building TSI` is of type `number`. And I am adding class name `invalid` using `cellClassName`, something like:

```
classnames({
   invalid: !isPositiveNumber(params.value)
})
```

It works fine and renders class name and indicates error cells. The problem is, I want to count total number of error cells. The reason is, we only allow to save the grid values to the database, if there are no errors in any cells.

Solutions, I have tried so far:

1. Add state for `errorCount` and increment `errorCount` when I add class. This causes several re-renders and exceeds memory limit.
2. I tried to use `document.getElementByClassNames('invalid')` and check its length. It works only for the rendered item. That is to say, if excel file has more than 10 rows, it is paginated. The invalid cells count is only done for the currently rendered page.
3. I tried to use `preProcessEditCellProps` props to indicate error. However, I could not find anyway to get the total error cells count. Only thing, I could get out of this props is an ability to not allow user to enter incorrect value.
4. I even tried using `localStorage`. It has the exact same issue as solution number 2.

I would appreciate if anyone has faced similar scenario. It would be nice to get overall error cells count, so, I can enable to disable SAVE button.

One of the constraints that I have is the excel files are huge and contains on average of 30-40k rows and 25-40 columns. Adding state for each cells becomes less performant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what i understood from the question, you have the data for the DataGrid already prepared before setting it, you can simply filter the data object before like `const hasError = data.find((x) => !isPositiveNumber(x.tsi)) !== undefined`, and set the disable state for the export button, if this is not the case, please elaborate on how you get your data to show at the DataGrid

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais, I can see your point.  There were 2 issues that I encountered with this approach. 1) I have more than 15-30 predefined columns and different rules. I did something like `hasIntegerTypeError` or `hasEnumTypeError`.  2) And since, I had to check errors on event change (E.g. column edit, column delete, column rename), I increased or decreased the state on `onStateChange` props of MUI DataGrid. It results into multiple renders and finally bails by saying maximum render reached. This approach was my initial approach.

Comment: you could add an extra boolean column as `hide: true` for the "error state" of that specific row, (ps: define the columns you want to export in the `fields` property of [export options](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/grid-csv-export-options/#properties)), where the value of that column is true/false depending if all the other columns of that row are correct, then, on the DataGrid data, if any of the rows have that hidden column with true for error, you disable the Export Button

Comment: This does not really scale to be honest. My Excel files are huge and have an average of 30-40k rows and 15-30 columns. That means, I will end up having 2X number of cells. I think, I found an hacky approach, I will post my answer, just in case some needs it.

Comment: it's dificult to scale when you have 30-40k rows and you need to verify if all the columns are correct in each individual one, not mentioning they are editable aswell.
i think it would be better if the export button was always available, and on export, verify if all are correct, if not, give the user some info where the errors are. Also, i didnt said 1+ cell for each collumn, but only 1 extra cell that validates all of the other, and like i mentioned, you have the fields prop on the [export options](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/grid-csv-export-options/#properties)

Comment: can you provide the sandbox example? i would like to see how you resolved it

Answer (score 0):

Having another property in columns and referring to it before exporting for each cell/row can help.

In this example, invoke eligibleForExport function with the columns definiton and the actual data as parameters will give a boolean stating if error exists or not. Can be changed to count errors as well.

```
const isInvalidBuildingTSI=(value)=>!isPositiveNumber(value);

const isPositiveNumber=(num)=>num>=0;

const eligibleForExport=(columns,data)=>{
    return !(data.find(row=>columns.find(column=>row[column.field] 
        && typeof column["isValid"] === "function" && column["isValid"](row[column.field]))))
}

const columns = [
    {
        "field": "uwgroup",
        "headerName": "Group",
        "minWidth": 200,
        "editable": true
    },
    {
        "field": "Building TSI",
        "type": 'number',
        "flex": 1,
        "minWidth": 150,
        "editable": true,
        "isValid" : isInvalidBuildingTSI,
        "cellClassName":isInvalidBuildingTSI(param.value)?"invalid":""
    }
];
```

Comment: This is similar to the first comment provided by @Ricardo Dias Morais. It did not help to be honest. I found a fix and am going to create a sandbox and link as the answer. This might be helpful for someone. And it is easier with sandbox to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**If the initial data is always valid** an easy way to solve your issue would be to follow the DataGrid documentation about clients side validation:

> #### Client-side validation
>
> To validate the value in the cells, first add a
> `preProcessEditCellProps` callback to the [column definition](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/grid-col-def/) of
> the field to validate. Once it is called, validate the value provided
> in `params.props.value`. Then, return a new object contaning
> `params.props` and also the `error` attribute set to true or false. If
> the `error` attribute is true, the value will never be committed.
>
> ```
> const columns: GridColDef[] = [
>   {
>     field: 'firstName',
>     preProcessEditCellProps: (params: GridEditCellPropsChangeParams) => {
>       const hasError = params.props.value.length < 3;
>       return { ...params.props, error: hasError };
>     },
>   },
> ];
> ```

For your scenario this would result in the following:

```
const columns = [
    {
        "field": "uwgroup",
        "headerName": "Group",
        "minWidth": 200,
        "editable": true
    },
    {
        "field": "Amazing column Name ",
        "flex": 1,
        "minWidth": 150,
        "editable": true
    },
    {
        "field": "Building TSI",
        "type": 'number',
        "flex": 1,
        "minWidth": 150,
        "editable": true,
        preProcessEditCellProps(params) {
            const invalid = !isPositiveNumber(params.props.value);
            return { ...params.props, error: invalid };
        }
    },
    {
        "field": "dev",
        "flex": 1,
        "minWidth": 150,
        "editable": true
    }
]
```

There is an important difference with what you currently have. This validation only effects edits. So the initial data has to be valid. The advantage is that you no longer have to use `classnames({ invalid: !isPositiveNumber(params.value) })` and the save button can always be enabled, since all committed changes can be assumed to be valid.

If the initial data can be invalid, this is probably not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: My initial data can be invalid. And as it says in the documentation of `preProcessEditCellProps`, if the cell value is invalid, it will never be committed. I still want user to type incorrect value but highlighted as error cell. This requirements come from business side.